# Link to external edmx files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

Normally the edmx and other related entity framework files are embeded in the dll.

For our current project we would like to have them external to the dll in order to change the prefixes between environments.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio not to embed the edmx files?

For example:

DEV.Table1 in development

PROD.Table1 in production

If this info in in the dll, we cannot copy the dll's between environments and just change the info in web.config.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _the prefixes_. Is this different from having several assemblies that only contain the entity models?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the comment, I updated, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: You could make an ObjectContext factory that has a connection string injected into it.

Comment: Why would you want to have a prefix for the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [external EDMX file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/11/29/tip-45-how-to-swap-ef-metadata-at-runtime.aspx). As alternative you can also check [Model adapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) to support these changes without needs for external EDMX.